# How to iterate over multiple hash values with Espinita in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [Espinita](https://github.com/continuum/espinita) to keep track of changes to my model and have multiple attributes that I would like to display in the view.

I haven't figured out how to iterate over each value without using an `||` in the iterator. I want to get the attribute name, the changed value and the date.

This is show.html:

```
<% @contract.contract_information.history_from_audits_for([:contract_title, :assigned_to, :action_requested..:deadline]).each do |changes| %>

<tr>
  <%= changes[:contract_title] || changes[:assigned_to] || changes[:deadline] %>
  <%= changes[:changed_at].strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

How do I iterate over each audit without referencing the attribute name?

**UPDATE**

After making the recommended changes. I now receive the attributes/values in array form. Is there a way to beautify the results in the view?

Output

```
11/20/2019  [:contract_stage, ""] [:action_requested, ""] [:reason_for_contract_request, ""] [:existing_or_returning, ""] [:background_check_status, ""] [:priority, ""] [:deadline_date, Wed, 20 Nov 2019] [:commencement_date, Wed, 20 Nov 2019]  davie200
```

View

```
 <% @contract.contract_information.history_from_audits_for([:contract_stage, :action_requested, :reason_for_contract_request, :deadline_date, :commencement_date, :existing_or_returning, :background_check_status, :priority]).each do |audit| %>
          <% audit.except(:changed_at).each do |attribute, value| %>
            <tr>
             <td><%= audit[:changed_at].strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
              <td>
                <% value.each do |val| %>
                  <%= val %>
                <% end %>
              </td>
              <td><%= @contract.contract_information.audits.last.user.username %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: When Im read the docuenation correctly, it returns an array with of hashes, which should be pretty simple to handle. I am not sure if this logic belongs to your view.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an opportunity to update Espinita in your project, I would recommend you to do it because [they changed the format](https://github.com/continuum/espinita/commit/442be7470494291fd58caea1fff94cc3f60fa792#diff-17c2ff2b5a7163666ef4a508d9c34b2aR67) of the hash returned by `history_from_audits_for`.

In the newer version, you will have something like this in the "[History and Restoration](https://github.com/continuum/espinita#history-and-restoration)" documentation:

```rb
model.history_from_audits_for([:name, :settings])
=> [{:changes=>{:name=>"Baz", :settings=>""}, :changed_at=>2015-05-03 15:33:58 -0700},
 {:changes=>{:name=>"Arglebargle", :settings=>"IHOP"}, :changed_at=>2015-03-24 15:33:58 -0700},
 {:changes=>{:name=>"Walrus"}, :changed_at=>2014-05-13 15:33:58 -0700}]
```

and your iteration will be as simple as:

```rb
<% @contract.contract_information.history_from_audits_for([:contract_title, :assigned_to, :deadline]).each do |audit| %>
  <% audit[:changes].each do |attribute, value| %>
    <tr>
      <%= value %>
      <%= audit[:changed_at].strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But, if you don't have a chance and you are using Rails > 3.0.0 consider the following approach:

```rb
<% @contract.contract_information.history_from_audits_for([:contract_title, :assigned_to, :deadline]).each do |audit| %>
  <% audit.except(:changed_at).each do |attribute, value| %>
    <tr>
      <%= value %>
      <%= audit[:changed_at].strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

using [`Hash#except`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except).

Retrieve User from Audit

```
<%= @contract.contract_information.audits.last.user.username %>
```